# Github - How to edit github repository description ON MOBILE

Tags: github

Is there any way to edit the repository description on mobile?

I don't see the "about" settings button anywhere on my page nor do I see the "edit repository" button, and I can't hover over anything. And the option is not in the settings tab.

There are multiple files even folders in the repository and I am the owner of the repository.

Comment: are you talking about browser using mobile, github mobile app or third-party github apps? or all of them?

Comment: Trying to use browser version on mobile, if there is a app for IOS that can help edit the repository description I could use that also but haven't really looked into it. @eis